# how to write 'or' query using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i want to write a query like `select*from bookdetails where editionId=$edid1 or editionId=$edid2;` in Codeigniter query.

Below is my Codeigniter query

```
     public function get_rare_outofprintBooks($edid1,$edid2) 
     {
        $this->load->database();   
        $query = $this->db->get_where('bookdetails',array('edition_id'=>$edid1),array('edition_id'=>$edid2));  //i tried like this but its NOT Working  

   if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row)
            {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
        return false;
   }
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$this->db->where('editionId', $edid1);
$this->db->or_where('editionId', $edid2);
```

It's right in the documentation http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Answer (score 3):

```
$this->db->where('id',3);
$this->db->or_where('id',5);
```

Reference [Here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)